# App Cache Directory is not deleted after uninstall (Samsung Galaxy Tab A)

Tags: android, caching, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

As i already mentioned in the Title, i recognized some strange problems when i uninstall my App from the GooglePlayStore and reeinstall it. As you can see the App Cache Directory is not deleted, the App is called **net.example** :

```
shell@gt510wifi:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data $ ls -la
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_rw        0 2015-01-01 01:01 .nomedia
...
drwxrwx--x u0_a80   sdcard_rw          2017-01-27 09:30 flipboard.boxer.app
drwxrwx--x u0_a197  sdcard_rw          2017-03-01 17:47 net.example
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2016-12-29 14:00 shaders


 app is uninstalled, but cache and data directory persist:


shell@gt510wifi:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data $ ls -la
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_rw        0 2015-01-01 01:01 .nomedia
...
drwxrwx--x u0_a80   sdcard_rw          2017-01-27 09:30 flipboard.boxer.app
drwxrwx--x u0_a197  sdcard_rw          2017-03-01 17:47 net.example
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2016-12-29 14:00 shaders
shell@gt510wifi:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data $
```

From the Documentation:

> Note: When the user uninstalls your application, this directory and
>   all its contents are deleted. Also, the system media scanner does not
>   read files in these directories, so they are not accessible from the
>   MediaStore content provider. As such, you should not use these
>   directories for media that ultimately belongs to the user, such as
>   photos captured or edited with your app, or music the user has
>   purchased with your app—those files should be saved in the public
>   directories.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

So it seems to be a Samsung Bug which leads to Permission Errors after the App is reeinstalled:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/net.example/cache/FileCache/20b7a74246f5d80d92ba2e3d1918331cfb98fd11: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Maybe someone experienced a similiar Bug on a Samsung Device?

**EDIT:** I already implemented the `"allowBackup:false"` in the Manifest, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: android manifest try adding , allowBackUp : false

Comment: From android 6 onwards a backup of the app storage will be kept by google and it doesnt clear the app data. Im pretty sure this is what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your response, please see my edit!

Comment: seeing this also for an app we work on. Wonder if there's a Samsung bug filed for this already and if Samsung has looked into it or not.